# running Gulp gives throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: javascript, npm, reactjs, gulp

[image]

> main.js

```
var React = require('react'); 
 var App = require('./components/app.js');
 React.render(
<App />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

> app.js

```
var React = require('react'); 
  var App = React.createClass({
render: function(){
    return (
        <p>Hello</p>
    );
}
});
module.exports = App;
```

is there any problem in gulpfile.js? because it works fine if i write react component code inside main.js file.

Comment: Try placing a string around the HTML from the syntax error on app.js line 9.

Comment: I guess you don't have JSX compiler ?

Comment: @JSess: That's JSX, not HTML.

Comment: Now i am clear about what my problem is. Actually my jsx code of main.js is getting compiled but jsx of app.js is not, because when i replace jsx code of app.js with plain javascript then it runs perfectly.

Comment: /** @jsx React.DOM */   i just added this on top of my app.js and main.js file and it worked finally. Can anyone tell me why i need to add those pragma on top of each file??

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to transform your JSX into Javascript.

Here's my gulp build task - It uses browserify and reactify to transform and bundle my components, then minifies them, and finishes by placing them into a directory that my application reads from.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var reactify = require('reactify');
var streamify = require('gulp-streamify');

gulp.task('build', function () {
    browserify({
        entries : ['./js_modules/main.js'],
        transform : [reactify],
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(streamify(uglify('bundle.js')))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/main/webapp/js/bundle.js'));
});
```